# Add Timestamp to Update Tab onEdit of Main Tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to have it that when a row is edited that it only copies the name, phone and adds a timestamp of the edit on another tab in Google Sheets. Each row on Update sheet should be a new row from edit.

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  var date  = new Date();
  var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIdx,1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(rowValues);
  var destValues = [];
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][0]);// copy data from col A to col A
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][2]);// copy data from col C to col B
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][1]);// copy data from col B to col C
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][3]);// copy data from col D to col D

  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Updates');
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);



}
```

The above is working but i cannot figure out how to get the timestamp to show.

The outcome should display the roadname, phone and then C:C should have timestamp of change made.

I have updated the below sheet to show expected outcome

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V3Ne9L0kB97OkFKwlidx40yN__sx78aRik_Ujiej2Wc/edit#gid=1523701088

Expected outcome of 2nd Tab

| Roadname | Phone | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Edit 1 | 555-5555 | 2/16/2023 09:14:52 |
| edit 2 | 555-5555 | 2/16/2023 09:14:52 |
| Edit 3 | 555-5555 | 2/16/2023 09:14:52 |
| Edit 4 | 555-5555 | 2/16/2023 09:14:52 |

Data Table:

| Road Name | Date Contacted | Phone number | Clan Name | State | Status | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name2 | 2/1/23 | 5551212222 |  |  |  | Some Comment 1 |
| Name1 | 2/1/23 | 5551212222 |  |  |  | Some comment 2 |
| Name4 | 2/1/23 | 5551212222 |  |  |  | Called him |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: This question seems to be a copy of [Copy certain cells to another sheet on edit with timestamp](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/202124886). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  }
  let sheet;
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 7 || !(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/^(Main)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const rowValues = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const destValues = [0, 2].map(index => rowValues[index]).concat([new Date()]);
  e.source.getSheetByName('Updates').appendRow(destValues);
}
```

See [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Worked great.